# Routes behaviour inconsistent between server and local Rails with aliased resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a rails app using Rails 2.2.2 and ruby 1.8.6 (i know i should update, don't go there).

I have this entry in my `config/routes.rb` file:

```
map.namespace :music_service_admin do |music_service_admin|
  music_service_admin.resources :users, :as => :teachers
end
```

Which gives me urls like

```
/music_service_admin/teachers
/music_service_admin/teachers/123 
etc
```

I just had a bug where i had accidentally used `/music_service_admin/users` in an ajax call.  I missed the bug because on my local machine, in development OR production mode, both these routes work:  I can use ALL of the `/music_service_admin/teachers` routes with "/users" instead of "/teachers", and they behave the same.

On our server, however, it will only accept the `/music_service_admin/teachers` routes - the `/music_service_admin/users` urls aren't recognised and therefore 404.

In both instances (server and local), if i look at rake routes it only has routes for the `/music_service_admin/teachers` urls: it doesn't have any for `/music_service_admin/users`.  So, according to rake routes, i'd expect `/music_service_admin/users` to NOT work on my machine.  So i guess it's my local rails that's anomalous, and the server is behaving as expected.

Any ideas why it might be different?

Comment: as they are naming routes...they will work for both teachers and users...try using without :as...i will work for only users/teachers whichever you choose...give it a try :()

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't address why it behaves differently in the two environments.  Are you saying that it is *supposed* to accept `/music_service_admin/users` AND `/music_service_admin/teachers` in all cases?  If i try it without the `:as => :teachers` then i won't be able to use the /teachers urls at all.